# Rails 3 way working with multiple if statements and form create/new

Tags: activerecord, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-3.2, multiple-instances

I have a problem to approach and not sure what the most appropriate method will be to make this work. Here the background to begin:

There are two models I am working with Procedures and Appointments. The Appointments model belongs_to the Procedures model and Procedures model has_many Appointments.

Now on the procedures model there are two key points to focus on, rather, two key columns.

`attr_accessible :visits, :occurence`

visits is the specific number of times to schedule the Appointment(s).
occurence is the frequency of the visits. An example would be `visits: "5", occurence: "weekly"`

So when I am submitting my form I would like to write a method that looks at both `visits: "x"` and `occurence: ["weekly", "biweekly", "monthly"]` to then create a if or a switch -- php does switch still looking into ruby version -- but I suspect there is an elegant way to write this up.

My current create method looks like this:

```rb
def create
  @appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment])
  set_variables
  if @appointment.save
    flash[:success] = "Appointment scheduled!"
    redirect_to patient_path(@current_patient)
  else
    redirect_to patient_path(@current_patient)
    flash[:error] = "Appointment Date and Time cannot be blank, please try again."
  end
end
```

What would be the best way to tackle a) identifying `occurence: ["weekly", "biweekly", "monthly"]` and then processing `visits: "x"` based on something similar to:

```rb
if @appointment.occurence == "weekly"
  (x-1).times do |n|
    submit same params but change within params appointment_date: = ((@appointment.appointment_date) + (n+1).week.to_formatted_s(:db)
    @appointment.save
  end
end
```

...and so on and so forth using `(n+1).month` for monthly occurrence `(n+2).day` and for bi-weekly occurrence(s).

Thank you in advance, hope this clarifies things. Just one item to note, do I need to store in database `visits:` and `occurence:`, I suspect not but would like to be certain they are used when hitting the models_controller create function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly less cluttered solution that should do what you need, though it also assumes that you get rid of the `:appointment_date` field and change `:appointment_time` to a `DateTime` field. For more info on **DateTimes** check out:

(Stackoverflow will only allow me to post 2 links because I'm a n00b so search "DateTime Ruby" on your favorite search engine for documentation for the Ruby and rails methods for DateTime)

Formatting DateTime to string for views: http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

Intro on using DateTimes in forms: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-date-and-time-form-helpers

```
@appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment])
set_variables
if @appointment.save 
    if @procedure.occurence == "WEEKLY"
       multiplier = 7
    elsif @procedure.occurence == "BIWEEKLY"
       multplier = 14
    else
       multiplier = 30
    end

    @visits = @procedure.visits - 1
    @visits.times do |n|
        Appointment.create!(
            :procedure_id => @appointment.procedure_id,
            :patient_id => @appointment.patient_id,
            :appointment_time => (@appointment.appointment_time + (multiplier * n).days),
            :attendance => "SCHEDULED"
        )
    end
else
    flash.now[:error] = "There appears to be an error, please try again."
    render 'new'
end
```

Comment: This is a lovely and welcome change! Thank you for the spending the time to write this up.

Answer (score 0):

Solved for the moment, rather crude--as is my current ruby skill set--but it seems to have done the job.

```
     @appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment])
            set_variables
            @appointment.save
            if @procedure.occurence == "BIWEEKLY"
                    @visits = @procedure.visits - 1
                    @visits.times do |n|
                            procedure_id = @appointment.procedure_id
                            patient_id = @appointment.patient_id
                            appointment_date = (@appointment.appointment_date + 
                                    ((n+2)*2).days).to_formatted_s(:db)
                            appointment_time = @appointment.appointment_time
                            appointment_notes = @appointment.appointment_notes
                            attendance = "SCHEDULED"
                            @scheduled = Appointment.create(procedure_id: procedure_id, 
                                    patient_id: patient_id, appointment_date: appointment_date, 
                                    appointment_time: appointment_time, 
                                    appointment_notes: appointment_notes, attendance: attendance)
                    end
            end
            if @procedure.occurence == "WEEKLY"
                    @visits = @procedure.visits - 1
                    @visits.times do |n|
                            procedure_id = @appointment.procedure_id
                            patient_id = @appointment.patient_id
                            appointment_date = (@appointment.appointment_date + 
                                    (n+1).week).to_formatted_s(:db)
                            appointment_time = @appointment.appointment_time
                            appointment_notes = @appointment.appointment_notes
                            attendance = "SCHEDULED"
                            @scheduled = Appointment.create(procedure_id: procedure_id, 
                                    patient_id: patient_id, appointment_date: appointment_date, 
                                    appointment_time: appointment_time, 
                                    appointment_notes: appointment_notes, attendance: attendance)
                    end
            end
            if @procedure.occurence == "MONTHLY"
                    @visits = @procedure.visits - 1
                    @visits.times do |n|
                            procedure_id = @appointment.procedure_id
                            patient_id = @appointment.patient_id
                            appointment_date = (@appointment.appointment_date + (n+1).month).to_formatted_s(:db)
                            appointment_time = @appointment.appointment_time
                            appointment_notes = @appointment.appointment_notes
                            attendance = "SCHEDULED"
                            @scheduled = Appointment.create(procedure_id: procedure_id, 
                                    patient_id: patient_id, appointment_date: appointment_date, 
                                    appointment_time: appointment_time, 
                                    appointment_notes: appointment_notes, attendance: attendance)
                    end
            end
```

Comment: I suspect there is a cleaner way to write/present this code but this is what is working for me at the moment. Comments are welcome. Criticism is greatly appreciated! (will help on my improving cleaner code)